# Find error in following sentence:

Tags: error

> ***Rosy has / an urgent work / at home / today / No Error***

I am trying to find an anwer to this sentence. Most of my friends say there aren't any errors, but a few say *'an urgent work'* has an error.

Comment: Why are there '/' (Slashes) in between the words?

Comment: @VarunKN I think it's an example from an ESL class where you underline the part of the sentence that has the error.

Comment: Oh okay, I had no idea what that was for.

Answer (score 5):

I think "an urgent work" is the error. "Urgent work" is not a countable type of work, but "an" implies a single, countable item. Therefore, the word "an" should be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm siding with Ringo on this one, you can't put "an" before work in this case as it's not countable. You would say "I have work to do", not "I have a work to do".

However, there are other contexts in which you could encounter **a work** and **works**, when for instance talking about arts (see [Work of art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_of_art)).

Comment: Agreed, but I think this should have been a comment.

Comment: Agreed, but I didn't have the 50 required street cred to comment 6 hours ago :<.